# Reference request for result: Martin's Axiom implies there are $(\mathfrak{c}, \mathfrak{c})$-gaps

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I'm looking for a reference to the possible theorem in the title.  I have a proof in mind that uses MA (and a kind of double Hechler forcing) to fill all the $(<\mathfrak{c}, <\mathfrak{c})$-pre-gaps, and then use a similar proof to the existence of $(\omega_1, \omega_1)$-gaps (using the fact that $(\omega, \omega)$-gaps do not exist) to show that $(\mathfrak{c}, \mathfrak{c})$-gaps do exist (using the fact that $(<\mathfrak{c}, <\mathfrak{c})$ do not exist).

At some point I felt like I found this theorem with a reference to a paper by Kunen possibly, but now I cannot find the reference, and I never did find the original paper with the proof.  Does anyone know where to find this theorem?

Comment: Probably not the answer, but a good place to start looking: https://doi.org/10.2178/jsl/1067620186

Comment: Thank you Asaf, it looks like that paper references this theorem or something like it, though I can't see the paper.  Is it true that MA implies there are $(\mathfrak{c}, \mathfrak{c})$-gaps, is this a known result?

Comment: So I got the paper now, it refers to a "handwritten note" by Kunen from 1976 where he shows that MA is consistent with "there are $({\frak c,c})$-gaps" and it is consistent with "there are no $({\frak c,c})$-gaps" as well.

Comment: Thank you Asaf, that is very interesting!  I am now very curious about how it is consistent with no $(\mathfrak{c}, \mathfrak{c})$-gaps.

Comment: From the paper: *The main idea of his proof of the consistency of statement 2 is to construct a finite support iteration forcing MA and forcing $(\omega_1,\omega_1)$-gaps to be indestructible as far as possible (see also [14]). Letting $({\scr A,B})$ be an $(\omega_1,\omega_1)$-gap, when $({\scr A,B})$ is forced to be indestructible, we call $({\scr A,B})$ frozen. To freeze $(\omega_1,\omega_1)$-gaps, he used ccc forcing notions.* (statement 2 is the consistency of MA with no $({\frak c,c})$-gaps.)

Comment: Also from the paper, it seems Todorcevic showed that PFA implies that there are no such gaps, which implies that MA is consistent with that as well (modulo large cardinals, which are unnecessary for the result, of course). The references given for this are Todorcevic "Partition problems in topology" and Baumgartner "Applications of the proper forcing axiom".

Comment: Kunen's proof sounds literally cool.  Thank you so much.  And I see, Todorcevic's result holds because PFA implies MA?

Comment: Yes, PFA implies MA, quite trivially, so Todorcevic's result is in some sense a stronger one. It shows that the fact that MA is even consistent with $({\frak c,c})$-gaps is because it's just too weak to disprove their existence entirely.